# Type mistmatch when trying to write to Bigtable using BigtableIO.Write()

Tags: scala, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

I am attempting to write to Bigtable with BigtableIO v2.43.0.

My source data is a `PCollection[BigtableRow]` where `BigtableRow` is an internally defined construct.

Following the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.43.0/) for `BigtableIO.Write`, I have the following:

```
val items = PCollection[BigtableRow]
...
val write: Write = BigtableIO
  .write()
  .withProjectId(adaptor.projectId)
  .withInstanceId(adaptor.instanceId)
  .withTableId(adaptor.tableName)

items
  .apply(MapElements.via(BigtableRowToWrite))
  .apply(write)
```

From the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.43.0/) I see that `Bigtable.Write` should be applied on a `PCollection<KV<ByteString, Iterable<Mutation>>>` so I have the following helper function to convert the original data source of `PCollection[BigtableRow]`:

```
object BigtableRowToWrite extends SimpleFunction[BigtableRow, KV[ByteString, Iterable[Mutation]]] {
  override def apply(input: BigtableRow): KV[ByteString, Iterable[Mutation]] = {
    val mutations: Seq[Mutation] = input.columns.map { c =>
      Mutation
        .newBuilder().setSetCell(Mutation.SetCell.newBuilder().setValue(ByteString.copyFrom(c.valueBytes))).build()
    }

    KV.of(ByteString.copyFrom(input.keyBytes), mutations)
  }
}
```

This code is not able to compile and raises the following:

```
[error]  found   : org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigtable.BigtableIO.Write
[error]  required: org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform[_ >: org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection[org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV[com.google.protobuf.ByteString,Iterable[com.google.bigtable.v2.Mutation]]], ?]
```

I am not able to see what I'm doing wrong, could someone please point out my error?

Comment: Hi @czchlong, Are you using Google cloud dataflow?<br>

Comment: Hi @DhirajSingh I am using Google cloud Dataflow

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? If yes, please post an answer.